# How to disable test suite in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest

How to disable a test suite, i.e. all tests inside class extending `FunSpec`?

The only solution I'd found is to replace `it` with `ignore` in front of each test, but it is boring to do so with the dozens of tests.

Comment: Whatever you do, [don't comment it out :)](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1334908)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The easy way to do this in 1.8 is to add a constructor that takes a dummy argument. ScalaTest (and sbt) won't discover the class if it doesn't have a public, no-arg constructor:

```
class MySuite(ignore: String) extends FunSuite { 
  // ...
}
```

In 2.0 you'll be able to just write @Ignore on the class:

```
@Ignore
class MySuite extends FunSuite {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it had no affect I am using scala 2.10.2, please help me out. @BillVenners

Answer (score 7):

You can use [@Ignore](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.1.0/index.html#org.scalatest.Ignore) both for distinct tests and the whole suit.

Answer (score 7):

Per [scalatest](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/tagging_your_tests) docs, say if you have a test suite like this

```
describe ("some component") {
  it ("should do something") {
   ...
  }
  it ("should also do something else") {
   ...
  }
}
```

To disable just a single test, you can use the `ignore()` method.

```
describe ("some  component") {
  ignore ("should do something") {
   ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use *@DoNotDiscover*

From the [scaladoc](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/DoNotDiscover.html):

```
import org.scalatest._

@DoNotDiscover
class SetSpec extends FlatSpec {

  "An empty Set" should "have size 0" in {
    assert(Set.empty.size === 0)
  }

  it should "produce NoSuchElementException when head is invoked" in {
    intercept[NoSuchElementException] {
      Set.empty.head
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: DoNotDiscover works better than Ignore when you have test (class) constructor code that may fail at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

[Tag](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/tagging_your_tests) the troublesome tests and then [exclude or include](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner#filtering) tests based on the tag.

Tagging is a one time effort.

Answer (score 2):

Tags are one option, but you need to tag each tests accordingly, you cannot exclude complete suits that way. However, as user272735 mentioned, tagging tests is a one time effort.

Another option is defining a master suite and limiting the list of `nestedSuites` to the suites you would like to run ([see the docs](http://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/1.6.1/#org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll)). The obvious disadvantage is, that you have to maintain the master test suite, i.e., add newly created test suites to it. You could avoid this by recursing through your folders, creating a list of all test suits that can be found, and subtracting those that you put into a black list. In addition, recursing through your folders already gives you an opportunity the filter out files that match an (externally) given criterion.

A third option - albeit more hacky - is to change the package to which the suites you want to black list belong. You can then use a test runner to only run suits included in certain packages. Read more in the docs, section ["Specifying 'members-only' and 'wildcard' Suite paths"](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner#filtering).